# cmake set subdirectory options

Tags: cmake

Is there anyway to set the options of a subdirectory?

So I have a project that depends on a subproject, the subproject has an option:

```
OPTION(WITH_FUNCTION_X "enable X functionality" ON)
```

And in my parent project I want to include the subproject, but without functionality X.

thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

CMake's `option` command more or less adds a boolean variable to the cache.

If you want to override the default value of an option, simply add a variable of the same name to the cache yourself before pulling in the subproject:

```
set(WITH_FUNCTION_X OFF CACHE BOOL "enable X functionality")
add_subdirectory(subproject)
```

Note that the `set` command does nothing if there is already a value of that name in the cache. If you want to overwrite any existing value, add the `FORCE` option to that command.

Sample with `FORCE`

```
set(WITH_FUNCTION_X OFF CACHE BOOL "enable X functionality" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(subproject)
```

Comment: Seems that `set()` has different effects between CMake on Mac and Linux (or perhaps different releases?!?).  Hit this one myself today and drove me crazy until I used the `CACHE BOOL "text"` option to set.  Without the `CACHE` it worked fine on the Mac, but not on Linux.

Comment: Use `INTERNAL` instead of `BOOL` if you want to hide it (from CMake GUI), like ```set(WITH_FUNCTION_X OFF CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)```